Using different conjunctions istead of "if"

He might have done it provided you had helped him

Wrong, we don't use on condition, provided, and as long as with the 3rd conditional.

He might have done it if/provided you opened the door.

It's ok right, because it's not a conditional?

Provided you did it, I will not speak to you again.

Here provided can be used. What about a mix of 2 and 3 or 3 and 2?

Provided I was smarter, I wouldn't have happened.
Provided you hadn't cheated on her, she would be with us now.


On condition she arrived, I would give her something to eat.
This is not a typical conditional, so is it possible to use “on condition“,  “provided“ and “as long as“ instead of “if“?


When you say a mix of "2 and 3 OR 3 and 2" are you talking about the sentences in the question  or 1st/ first, 2nd/ second, and 3rd/ third conditional? How you present and organise your question must be made clearer and be without ambiguity. Proofread your examples, carefully e.g. “Provided I was smarter, I wouldn't have happened.” Does not make sense. You meant to say It wouldn't have happened

These web pages ought to help you PROVIDING that you also study :-) 1 Unless, even if, provided, as long as, 2 Exercise practice 3 Unless, Providing, Provided & As Long As Quiz

(1), (2) and (3) are all wrong because provided that is only used to state a condition necessary for a future action. (As you were told in the answer to your previous question.)

I will give her something to eat provided/on condition that she doesn't arrive too late.

'He might have done it if you had opened the door' is a conditional. I feel it needs the past perfect because 'opening the door' needed to happen before 'doing it'.

what about 2 conditional for instance "provided you cooked I would give you a kiss" and 0 zero "provided you cook I kiss you"?

I erm.. edited the question, the intention was to make the OP's sentences stand out more. You might want to edit your answer accordingly (or you might not).

Thomas, neither of those sentences makes sense. Someone might possibly say "Provided you promise to cook for me tonight, I will give you a kiss".

@KateBunting Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Thank you very much for your help!
